# Can not set font-weight for pseudo-states in qt

Tags: css, qt

I'm facing a problem in which I want to make the font bold in an QPushButton when it is hovered or pressed. But font-weight property only works in normal state, on font state it doesn't affect anything.
I'm really looking for a solution.

Comment: Sad, but true: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-8990 I can't believe it's 2012 and it's still unresolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me--the style sheet font properties are ignored in the hover state. I was not able to come up with a workaround using style sheets, but you can always subclass `QPushButton` to get what you need:

```cpp
#include <QtGui>

class HoverablePushButton : public QPushButton {
public:
  HoverablePushButton(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = NULL)
    : QPushButton(text, parent) {}

protected:
  void enterEvent(QEvent *event) {
    QPushButton::enterEvent(event);
    QFont f(font());
    f.setBold(true);
    setFont(f);
  }

  void leaveEvent(QEvent *event) {
    QPushButton::leaveEvent(event);
    QFont f(font());
    f.setBold(false);
    setFont(f);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  HoverablePushButton b("hello!");
  b.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Might be overkill, but if the functionality is critical for your application, it is at least one workaround.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I have read somewhere that font properties are only supported if the object is a widget and pseudo-states aren't just any widget (though I think this's a funny way to explain, why doesn't qt support these properties upon pseudo-state out-of-the-box?).